# How to stop the Tinkerbell mouse effect from activating horizontal scrollbar and increasing the page width?

Tags: javascript

I tried Tinkerbell mouse effect [from this website.](http://www.mf2fm.com/rv/dhtmltinkerbell.php)

The problem is when you press the mouse wheel while moving to the right side of the page, it widens and horizontal scrollbar appears.
I don't want to just hide the scrollbar but stop the page from widening. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Where are you running into trouble with what you've attempted so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates an absolute divs that makes the page expand. You can limit it in the following way.

```
function mouse(e) {
if (e) {
    if (e.pageX < (screen.width * 9/10)) {
        y=e.pageY;
        x=e.pageX;

    }
}
    else {
    set_scroll();
    y=event.y+sdown;
    x=event.x+sleft;
     }
}
```

This will cause the code to work only on 90% (9/10) of the screen on the left.